# Do we need to create new Intent for every startService on an IntentService?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

As the question mentions, I am re-using the same Intent object, reloading it with different extras data, before using it in startService. Is this OK? or do I need to do a "new Intent(context, ServiceClass)" before every startService?

I am using the Service for continuous stream of processing so I am a bit concerned if I have to create a new Intent everytime I need to send the data to the Service.

The problem is that currently, the Service seems to get executed only once. All subsequent startService calls don't seem to fire the Service. What can be the reason?

EDIT: Adding code

This is the main activity:

```
public class Measurement extends Activity{

    AudioRecord recorder;   
    int iAudioBufferSize;
    boolean bRecording; 
    int iBytesRead;


    // UI stuff 
    Button bt_Measure;
    Button bt_Stop; 
    RadioButton rd_Live;
    RadioButton rd_DataCollection;
    RadioButton rd_SampleCollection;
    Thread recordThread;
    Intent sampleDataIntent;


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
    super.onDestroy();
    if (recorder != null)
        recorder.release();     
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bt_Measure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_measure);
    bt_Measure.setEnabled(true);
    bt_Stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_stop);
    rd_Live = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_live);
    rd_DataCollection = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_datacollection);
    rd_SampleCollection = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_samplecollection);
    rd_Live.setChecked(true);

    bRecording = false;
    int iSampleRate = AudioTrack
            .getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
    iAudioBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(iSampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, iSampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            iAudioBufferSize);
    sampleDataIntent = new Intent(this, DetectionService.class);


    bt_Measure.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rd_Live.isChecked()){ // radio button for Live processing
                if (!bRecording) {                  
                    bt_Measure.setEnabled(false);
                    bt_Stop.setEnabled(true);
                    try {
                        recorder.startRecording();
                        bRecording = true;

                        recordThread = new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[iAudioBufferSize];                                 
                                int iBufferReadResult;
                                int iBytesToRead = iAudioBufferSize;
                                iBytesRead = 0;
                                while (!interrupted()) {
                                    iBufferReadResult = recorder.read(buffer,
                                            0, iBytesToRead);                                                                                   
                                    sampleDataIntent.removeExtra("THE_DATA");
                                    sampleDataIntent.putExtra("THE_DATA", buffer);
                                    sampleDataIntent.putExtra("FRAME_SIZE", iBufferReadResult);
                                    startService(sampleDataIntent);                                                                                 
                                    iBytesRead = iBytesRead + iBufferReadResult;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        recordThread.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        tv_Speed.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

This is the Detection Serice:

```
public class DetectionService extends IntentService {


ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
byte[] sampleBuffer;
byte[] lastSampleBuffer;
PeakFilter peakFilter1;
PeakFilter peakFilter2;
PeakFilter peakFilter3;
PeakFilter peakFilter4;

float fSum = 0;
short sAvgAmpl = 0;
short sMaxAvg = 0;
short sPeakAmpl = 0;


public DetectionService() {
    super("DetectionService");
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    peakFilter1 = new PeakFilter(260, 20, 44100);
    peakFilter2 = new PeakFilter(260, 20, 44100);
    peakFilter3 = new PeakFilter(260, 20, 44100);
    peakFilter4 = new PeakFilter(260, 20, 44100);
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent sampleDataIntent) {
    try {
        baos.write(sampleDataIntent.getByteArrayExtra("THE_DATA"));
    } catch (IOException e1) {          
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (baos.size() > 44100 * 5) // 5 second frame
        sampleBuffer = baos.toByteArray();
    else
        return;

    try {

            // NON THREAD IMPEMENTATION
            // Threaded implementation has the same Try..Catch executed in
            // separate thread. Neither seems to be running more than once.

        short[] preFilterBuffer = new short[sampleBuffer.length/2];
        int iSample = 0;

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < preFilterBuffer.length; i++, j+=2){                          
            preFilterBuffer[iSample] = (short) (sampleBuffer[j+1] << 8 | sampleBuffer[j]);
            iSample++;
        }

        short[] FilteredSamples = new short[preFilterBuffer.length];            
        // Filters are not spawning threads. Purely Math processing.
        peakFilter1.filter(FilteredSamples, preFilterBuffer, preFilterBuffer.length);
        peakFilter1.amplify(FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples, 3);
        peakFilter2.filter(FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples.length);
        peakFilter2.amplify(FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples, 3);
        peakFilter3.filter(FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples.length);
        peakFilter3.amplify(FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples, 2);
        peakFilter4.filter(FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples, FilteredSamples.length);

        // LOT OF MATH on filtered samples
        // ......
        // 
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();            }


}
```

Comment: "_All subsequent startService calls don't seem to fire the Service_" - what exactly do you mean by this - doesn't the `#onStartCommand(..)` get called every time you call `#startService(..)` - or are you referring to `#onCreate()`? Your use-case seems to imply that you should consider extending the framework class `IntentService` instead.

Comment: `sampleDataIntent.removeExtra("THE_DATA");
           sampleDataIntent.putExtra("THE_DATA", buffer);
           sampleDataIntent.putExtra("FRAME_SIZE", iBufferReadResult);
           startService(sampleDataIntent); ` This is what I do everytime I call the startService. I do this in a continuous loop. The flow seems to reach the onHandleIntent handler Service only in the first iteration. I have tried disconnecting the main thread and only debugging the Service after the first call. I keep waiting forever and the flow never reaches the onHandleIntent again for any of the subsequent calls.

Comment: What are you doing in your `onHandleIntent` - is it a long-running operation? The `IntentService` is single-threaded and will wait until the first operation is done until it starts the next.

Comment: I AM starting another thread inside the onHandleIntent. Can we not start another thread in an IntentService and exit the current flow?

Comment: Hm, I'd suggest you post a bit of code so we can see what you are doing. Spawning threads in the worker thread of the `IntentService` shouldn't pose a problem in it self unless you are calling `join` or otherwise blocking on the thread of course.

Comment: I had added code, but no one seemed to respond. Anyway, I resolved this myself. The reason for not executing the Service more than once was a NullPointerException on write to ByteArrayOutputStream which was not shown in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can add methods to your service, for example `putData(...)`… After starting the service, if it's… alive, I think you just use it as an object.